No puedo moverme por el TabBar de mi app usando el control del TV
llevo semanas intentando crear una app para TV usando React-native y Expo. Al principio tenia muchos problemas con el foco de los elementos cuando usaba el control remoto del TV, pero luego de que instale react-native-tvos y configure mi proyecto para usarlo, todo comenzo a funcionar sin ningun problema y el TV me reconoce los elementos sobre los cuales estoy mientras uso el control remoto
El problema que tengo ahora es con el TabBar. He creado una barra de navegacion horizontal en la parte inferior de la pantalla usando React Navigation (no estoy usando Expo-router) y no puedo navegar en ella usando el control remoto, solo funciona cuando doy click sobre ella, del resto no.
He intentado muchas cosas distintas como crear un proyecto desde cero usando el comando que ofrece Expo para tv "npx create-expo-app MyTVProject -e with-tv", limpiar el cache de Metro, utilizar Yarn en vez de NPM, eliminar y reinstalar la carpeta de NODE_MODULES, y muchas otras cosas pero no he tenido exito con ninguna y ya llevo como 10 dias sin tener ningun progreso y me estoy quedando sin ideas
Apreciaria mucho si alguien me pudiera ayudar con esto, gracias de antemano!
Package.json
{
  "name": "tv",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.23.1",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "^4.5.2",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.20",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.17",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.26",
    "expo": "~51.0.13",
    "expo-av": "^14.0.5",
    "expo-dev-client": "~4.0.18",
    "expo-font": "^12.0.7",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~13.0.2",
    "expo-screen-orientation": "^7.0.5",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.27.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.12.1",
    "expo-updates": "^0.25.17",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "npm:react-native-tvos@~0.74.2-0",
    "react-native-cache": "^2.0.3",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.4.11",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.10.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.31.1",
    "react-native-url-polyfill": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-video": "^6.2.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.24.0",
    "@react-native-tvos/config-tv": "^0.0.10",
    "@types/react": "~18.2.45",
    "typescript": "~5.3.3"
  },
  "expo": {
    "install": {
      "exclude": [
        "react-native"
      ]
    }
  },
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  }
}

app.json
{
  "expo": {
    "plugins": [
      [
        "@react-native-tvos/config-tv",
        {
          "androidTVBanner": "./assets/images/icon-400x240.png",
          "appleTVImages": {
            "icon": "./assets/images/icon-1280x768.png",
            "iconSmall": "./assets/images/icon-400x240.png",
            "iconSmall2x": "./assets/images/icon-800x480.png",
            "topShelf": "./assets/images/icon-1920x720.png",
            "topShelf2x": "./assets/images/icon-3840x1440.png",
            "topShelfWide": "./assets/images/icon-2320x720.png",
            "topShelfWide2x": "./assets/images/icon-4640x1440.png"
          }
        }
      ]
    ],
    "name": "tv",
    "slug": "tv",
    "android": {
      "package": "com.danielalves1501.tv"
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "62af12a8-1e44-4489-9fb8-ab4d0558e79e"
      }
    }
  }
}

AppStack.js
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import React from "react";
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";
import HomePage from "../screens/HomePage";
import Series from "../screens/Series";
import Saved from "../screens/Saved";
import Profile from "../screens/Profile";
import MaterialCommunityIcons from "@expo/vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons";
import Ionicons from "@expo/vector-icons/Ionicons";
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";
import ChooseProfile from "../screens/ChooseProfile";
import { colors } from "../constants/colors";
import { useAuthContext } from "../context/authContext";
// import useOrientation from "../hooks/useOrientation";
import MoviePlayer from "../screens/MoviePlayer";
import MovieDetails from "../screens/MovieDetails";

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const AppStack = () => {

  const { currentProfile } = useAuthContext();
  // const orientation = useOrientation();

  const TabIcon = ({ focused, color, icon, name, iconProvider }) => {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          alignItems: "center",
          justifyContent: "center",
          width: 100,
        }}
      >
        <Text>
          {iconProvider === "Ionicons" ? (
            <Ionicons
              name={icon}
              size={18} //FIX LATER orientation === "PORTRAIT" ? 20 : 18
              color={color}
            />
          ) : (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons
              name={icon}
              size={18} //FIX LATER orientation === "PORTRAIT" ? 20 : 18
              color={color}
            />
          )}
        </Text>
        <Text style={{ color: color, fontSize: 12 }}>{name}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  };

  const HomeStack = () => (
    <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
      <Stack.Screen name="HomePage" component={HomePage} />
      <Stack.Screen name="MovieDetails" component={MovieDetails} />
      <Stack.Screen name="MoviePlayer" component={MoviePlayer} />
      {/* Añadir la pantalla de detalles */}
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );

  if (currentProfile === null) {
    return (
      <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
        <Stack.Screen name="ChooseProfile" component={ChooseProfile} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <Tab.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
          headerShown: false,
          tabBarShowLabel: false,
          tabBarStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#363636",
            height: 70,
          },
        }}
      >
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={HomeStack}
          options={{
            title: "Home",
            tabBarInactiveTintColor: "#9796A9",
            tabBarActiveTintColor: "#DB6200",
            tabBarIcon: ({ color, focused }) => {
              return (
                <TabIcon
                  focused={focused}
                  color={color}
                  icon="home-sharp"
                  name="Home"
                  iconProvider="Ionicons"
                />
              );
            },
          }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Series"
          component={Series}
          options={{
            title: "Saved",
            tabBarInactiveTintColor: "#9796A9",
            tabBarActiveTintColor: "#DB6200",
            tabBarIcon: ({ color, focused }) => {
              return (
                <TabIcon
                  focused={focused}
                  color={color}
                  icon="filmstrip"
                  iconProvider="MaterialCommunityIcons"
                  name="Series"
                />
              );
            },
          }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Saved"
          component={Saved}
          options={{
            tabBarInactiveTintColor: "#9796A9",
            tabBarActiveTintColor: "#DB6200",
            tabBarIcon: ({ color, focused }) => {
              return (
                <TabIcon
                  focused={focused}
                  color={color}
                  icon="bookmark"
                  name="Saved"
                  iconProvider="Ionicons"
                />
              );
            },
          }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Profile"
          component={Profile}
          options={{
            title: "Profile",
            tabBarInactiveTintColor: "#9796A9",
            tabBarActiveTintColor: "#DB6200",
            tabBarIcon: ({ color, focused }) => {
              return (
                <TabIcon
                  focused={focused}
                  color={color}
                  iconProvider="Ionicons"
                  icon="person"
                  name="Profile"
                />
              );
            },
          }}
        />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    );
  }
};

export default AppStack;

